# how to write a function output in a file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

suppose i have a class of functions

```
class A:
    def func1():
        print(output.of.api)

    def func2():
        print(output.of.another.api)

#i make the required objects

func1_object = A()
func1_object.func1()
```

**it is required of me to write the output of these objects in a file.txt**

So I do this

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(func1_object.func())
```

which obviously gives me an error of

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

I have tried basic google solutions which obviously didn't work for me

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Well, how is that supposed to work? I mean your function has to return something to hand it like that to `f.write()`. Whatever the functions are supposed to do, can they not return the values you need?

Comment: The error you get pretty much tells you what to do: put a string param into the f.write method. In your case something like `func1_object.getApiOutput()`

Answer (score 2):

`func()` doesn't return anything. You have to return your output.

```
class A:
    def func1():
        return output.of.api

    def func2():
        return output.of.another.api
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    def func1():
        with open('file.txt','w') as f:
            print(str(output.of.api),file=f)
```

or return the values and write to a file as @rbcvi suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def func1():
        return output.of.api

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write((func1_object.func())
```

Currently your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I tried this method, it does write in the file but just prints **None** without the required output

Comment: That means the api doesn't return anything.